# Google Hangouts API - button to add/invite participant like in Toyoya Hangout App?

Tags: google-hangouts

Im trying to make an app for Google Hangouts using the API. I guess I'm not the only one who has this "problem".

I need to add participants automatically or semi automatically. But I can't find the way to do it. Today I've found an app that does something similar. It is called "[Toyoya Hangout App](https://developers.google.com/showcase/?hl=en#tags=hangouts&item=Toyota%20Hangout%20App)". There is a video explaining how it works. The point is that, at second 40 they add a participant by clicking a button called "Talk to an expert".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS0NABykrzU#t=38

Do some of you know how to do that? In the Youtube video description says that they have work with Google+ to do this app. Is that a functionality only for "Hangouts For Business"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the following for Hangout Button.

```
<div class="google_hangout" id="google_hangout">
  <h3 class="heading">Google Hangout with requestor</h3>
  <div id="placeholder-div"></div> 
</div>
```

Now, Asynchronously load JS and include parameters that you want to pass to the hangout when it gets initialised.

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); 
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButtons';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Here below, we will pass email as a string.

```
function renderButtons(){
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'invites' : "[{'id': 'test@test.com','invite_type': 'EMAIL'}]",
    'widget_size': 72
  });
}
```